NFS4 client only writes either 4kb or 128kb of data
I have a Debian NFS4 server that exports two volumes and several tens of Debian clients using these shares - mounted rw. Recently I noticed that some of these clients get into a strange state:
When the user tries to copy a file to the share on the client, only first 4kb, 32kb or 128kb is written to the file on the server. Then the client is waiting forever. No traffic on the NIC, no high load of the system, no problem reading from the local ssd. Nothing in any logs, nothing in dmesg. It seems that this issue is client specific because majority of the clients can write complete files without any issues.
Once this happens to the client, it is difficult to debug what is going on. rpcdebug hangs, dd of=/path/to/the/share hangs as well, any attempt to un/re/mount the shares hang, as well.
One common feature that seems to precede this issue is that the client needs to copy 32 files (each several hundreds of MB) from the local drive to the nfs share. However, again, it does not happen to all the clients with this task.
Neither seems busy or problematic the nfs server. I cannot easily restart it at this point, however, it seems that there are no issues.
Here are some more pieces of the information:

Kernel on the clients: 4.9.130
Kernel on the server: 6.1.38

/etc/exports of the server:
/exports                192.168.2.0/24(rw,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,async,no_root_squash)
/exports/data/tc    192.168.2.0/24(rw,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/exports/data/cc     192.168.2.0/24(rw,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)

/etc/fstab of the clients:
192.168.2.22:/data/tc  /data/tc    nfs   nfsvers=4,async,sec=sys,noacl,nocto,noatime 0       0
192.168.2.22:/data/cc  /data/cc    nfs   nfsvers=4,async,sec=sys,noacl,nocto,noatime 0       0

The output of the mount command on the client:
192.168.2.22:/data/tc on /data/tc type nfs4 (rw,noatime,vers=4.0,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,nocto,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.2.125,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.2.22)

/proc/net/rpc/nfsd of the server:
rc 0 129357384 4967412522
fh 1758 0 0 0 0
io 28313066211861 128215888716859
th 64 0 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
ra 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
net 801757532 0 801786350 360
rpc 801716819 0 0 0 0
proc2 18 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
proc3 22 2 38643 0 1 23508 8 11693 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1256 0 2 1 0
proc4 2 196 801713647
proc4ops 76 0 0 0 376804896 326418685 3744246955 991057 0 15175351 1176408590 99816225 336 270 0 270 128401154 0 0 349464595 0 443684 69904 5085654887 0 538 38596966 38506066 276542 7867733 723402 2399852 336 743994 0 22047360 157 157 0 224528399 12 0 61 148 170 158 132 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2584546568 0 24 0 142 130 0 20256 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20311 0 0 0 0 0 0

Jumbo packets set on all the devices involved in the connection (both nics and managed switch in between - 1Gbps ethernet). No firewall involved.
I would be thankful for any guess or any hint how to debug this issue.
I tried various ways of creating a file and copying it over nfs.

If you're confident in your underlying infrastructure, then some tweaks to how Linux handles NFS may help your situation. There's tons of things here ... but let's start slow.
You are likely running into system buffer constraints. You can observe this with nfsstat and nfsiostat well. To some extents you can see this with vmstat and iostat, but really you only see busyness and waits while no I/O is happening. It's super frustrating!
The bright side, you can probably do something about it?
Before jumping into things that may help ... please? for the LUV of all things cute & cuddly, double check and be extra double super duper sure you do NOT have any speed/duplex mismatch issues happening. If you have a managed switch, check on the switch that your interfaces are operating at the speed(s) you are expecting. Speed and/or Duplex mismatches ruin network performance and are so often totally overlooked!
Start with this - https://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/ar01s05.html
from Debian Forums - https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=68393
some of the same stuff from the first, but another source/location - https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NFS-HOWTO/performance.html
kernel tuning buffers for NFS performance - https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcp-tuning/
Lots more Linux NFS tuning knowledge that comes in handy - https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-tuning-nfs-server-client-performance/
Don't overlook the MTU on your network interface! It may be stuck at 1500 bytes which is obscenely small on gigabit ethernet! Especially if you're using Jumbo frames.

t3ln3t: Thank you for your reply. Actually, since I have been using nfs quite a lot in various situations, I have read these resources earlier and did the checks you pointed out, prior to writing my post here. Thank you. I will look into the options I have not implemented, so far (like kernel cache increase). It also seems that this issue happens when the user writes into a directory that already contains around 10.000 files. Can this have aby effect?

OH GOLLY YES! Very few technologies handle that scale well. Throw a network in the mix and things will get tediously slow. Simply put those in some sort of directory structure and things will work so much faster!
Bravo for doing some legwork and reading on the topic as well!
Finding the right mix of kernel level tunable parameters takes trial and error but will noticeable results.  Setup some rudimentary monitoring to reference in your annual review as well! NFS I/O wait decreased, utilization increased. Performance issues decreased... Good stuff!
